# Is there a C PHP extension for logging errors in a database?

Tags: php, php-extension

I know a multitude of workarounds (e.g., reading form syslog, custom error handler), though has anyone took time to write a C extension that would allow to store data to a RDMS?

Comment: Out of interest, why?

Comment: Primarily for maintanibility. Running multiple servers that report errors to a single database vastly cuts time on tracking down bugs across projects. Then there is speed, reduced IO, etc.

Comment: Collect your errors throughout the execution of your page. At the end of it (using a shutdown function, for example) you can bulk-insert your logs. Or use `syslog` and send that over to splunk where it can be aggregated.

Comment: What I meant was way you want to log errors through PHP extension? There are web server extensions which allow you logging errors to database. Then you can do error_log for application logs as well. Everythign should go to the one place.

Comment: Oh, I am doing that already. Well, I have custom error/exception handler that take cares of writing the error to the database while the `fastcgi_finish_request` makes sure that user does not need to wait for this to happen. Here is the code for those who are looking for an example, https://gist.github.com/gajus/18a74a62fee4f2a34bb7. Though, my question is if there is a C PHP module that does that already.

Comment: @LukaszKujawa I don't think that there is (or can be) a web-server (at least not for the NGINX, PHP-FPM combination) extension as such.

Comment: I'm surprised but you are right. It doesn't look like there is an obvious solution for Nginx. I would suggest to rephrase you question and focus on centralised logging for Nginx. PHP isn't the place to handle it (at least in my opinion)

Comment: Is there something wrong with using [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)?

Comment: You will need to set it for every project or include with auto prepend. With +10 projects on every of 5 servers, this isn't a fun thing to maintain.